# How to add a '₹' into a cell using excel vba (format a cell with a Currency symbol '₹' )

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am trying to format a cell using below code and I am expecting to set the currency symbol of that cell as '₹' Where i am getting INR values.

But when I add below VBA code, it remove the '₹' with a '?'

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$₹-hi-IN]#,##0.00"
```

VBA not able to recognise this symbol, Is it possible get this code working....

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried `Selection.NumberFormat = "#.##0,00_-[$₹-44D]"`?

Comment: Yes, VBA code is not accepting ₹ this symbol...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$" + ChrW(&H20B9) + "-hi-IN]#,##0.00"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
'simple currency
Selection.NumberFormat = ChrW(8377) & "#,##0.00"
'accounting format with red bracketed negatives
Selection.NumberFormat = "_(" & ChrW(8377) & "* #,##0.00_);[red]_(" & ChrW(8377) & "* (#,##0.00);_(" & ChrW(8377) & "* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
```